# How to set specific duration for properties

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I've tried to research the docs for a feature I feel like is missing, or I'm simply missing something.

In this example, I'm animating the `opacity` and `top` properties with a duration of 1 second.

```
$elements
    .velocity({opacity: 1, top: 0}, {duration: 1000})
```

Simple enough, but I want to tweak the animation a little. I'd like the `opacity` to have a duration of 2 seconds... But I can't seem to find an elegant way to achieve this.

I could always just repeat it like so:

```
$elements
    .velocity({top: 0}, {duration: 1000})

$elements
    .velocity({opacity: 1}, {duration: 2000})
```

... I'd like to avoid that spaghetti if possible.

Comment: Apparently my example of what could work, does not work. But it illustrates what I want to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

That was almost too easy!
I was not connecting that http://julian.com/research/velocity/#queue was just the thing I was missing :)

Example:

```
$elements
    .velocity({top: 0}, {duration: 1250})
    .velocity({opacity: 1}, {duration: 3000, queue: false})
    .velocity({opacity: 0}, {duration: 1000, delay: 2000})
```